# Retrieving password and username from keychainItemWrapper iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychainitemwrapper, security.framework

I'm trying to use the `KeychainItemWrapper.h` and `keychainWrapperItemWrapper.m` to store user credentials such as username and password. I currently store when user logs in for the first time like this:

```
KeychainItemWrapper* keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"login" accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:_usernameField.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
[keychain setObject:_passwordField.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

This stores the values in keychain. But the next time user opens app I want to retrieve the username and password again. However when i call the following:

```
NSString *password_ = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
NSString *username_ = [keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
```

It seems i get weird encrypted key such as: `<6f78696c 69676874 2d746573 74>`
Is there any way to retrieve the original strings for username and password?
I've never worked with keychain before, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code, although it looks like somewhere along the way an `NSString` is getting converted to `NSData`. The value `<6f78696c 69676874 2d746573 74>` is the `NSData` equivalent of the `NSString` "oxilight-test". Where did you get `KeychainItemWrapper.h` and how are you integrating it with your project? Are you using CocoaPods? Which version of Xcode are you using? What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: Are you using this? - https://gist.github.com/dhoerl/1170641. This script have lots of issues with it. Try some other like - https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2014/12/KeychainWrapper.zip | https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#keychain

Answer (score 1):

If you use the wrapper linked above, https://koenig-media.raywenderlich.com/uploads/2014/12/KeychainWrapper.zip. You can set username and password like this.
I renamed the methods for myObjectForKey and mySetObject. You can initialize

```
self.keychainWrapper = [[KeychainWrapper alloc] init];
```

in your init method.

```
//save user and password
[self.keychainWrapper setObject:username forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
[self.keychainWrapper setObject:_password forKey:(__bridgeid)kSecValueData];
[self.keychainWrapper writeToKeychain];

//retrieve username and password
NSString *username = [self.keychainWrapper objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
NSString *password = [self.keychainWrapper objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use this https://redflowerinc.com/keychain-wrapper-in-objective-c/

```
NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

@interface KeyChainWrapper : NSObject
+(NSMutableDictionary*) queryDictionary:(NSString*) identifier;
+(NSString*) searchKeychainCopyMatching:(NSString*) identifier;
+(bool) createKeychainValue:(NSString*) value forIdentifier:(NSString*) identifier;
+(bool) updateKeychainValue:(NSString*) password forIdentifier:(NSString*) identifier;
+(void) deleteKeychainValue:(NSString*) identifier;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```